# toggleClass (add if not present)

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

What is the simplest way to toggle a class if it is present, otherwise adding one if it's not?

Currently I'm using:

```
if ($(e.target).hasClass('clicked-odd')) {
  $(e.target).removeClass('clicked-odd');
  $(e.target).addClass('clicked-even');
} else {
  $(e.target).removeClass('clicked-even');
  $(e.target).addClass('clicked-odd');
}
```

... which seems a bit long.

You'd think this would work:

```
$(e.target).toggleClass('clicked-even', 'clicked-odd')
```

But it seems to only switch a class if it's present, but doesn't add 'clicked-odd' if neither class is present.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dennisbest/jRx3c/

Comment: Try this, `$(e.target).toggleClass('clicked-even clicked-odd')`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dennisbest/FGeeC/ This adds both classes.

Comment: It would you be easier if you didn't have two classes. What do you need them for? You could just use one class. For example, in your style sheet instead of `h1.clicked-odd { color: red } h1.clicked-even {color: blue}` just `h1 { color: red } h1.clicked-even {color: blue}`

Comment: Sure, it would be easier if did nothing at all. :) But I have plans for the unclicked element. No worries. I'll just stick with the if statement.

Comment: @DennisBest Then set a class on the unclicked element and toggle between `clicked-even` and no class: `<h1 class=unclicked>` and in the event handler: `$(e.target).removeClass('unclicked').toggleClass('clicked-even')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `toggleClass` calls toggles classes ok.

But to use it and for it to work as you wish, you need to have the class on your target first, if not, both classes will be added with the first toggle, and both removed on the second call.

If you want to start with no classes on your target, you need your `if` to insert one the first time.

Answer (score 1):

toggleClass will only work in the way you want it to if one of the classes is already present

Simplest way i can think of off the top of my head is

```
$(e.target).is('.clicked-even, .clicked-odd') ?
    $(e.target).toggleClass('clicked-even clicked-odd') : $(e.target).addClass('clicked-odd');
```